# Java Servlet Init Throws Exception When Calling this.getServletContext();

Tags: servlets

In my Java Servlet's init method, I am calling:

```
public void init (ServletConfig config) throws ServletException { 
    ServletContext context = this.getServletContext();
}
```

and its immediately throwing:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:123)
myproject.servlets.Login.init(Login.java:37)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overridden the `init(ServletConfig config)` method in your Servlet class and did not call the `super.init(config)` to do the standard setup stuff, resulting in an empty context.

```
public void init (ServletConfig config) throws ServletException { 
    super.init(config);
    ServletContext context = this.getServletContext();
}
```

Comment: Presuming all of that exists..and its still not working..then what?

Comment: @user4640007 If my answer solved this specific issue, then you should marked my answer as the correct one so the topic will be marked as solved. If you still have other issues you can post other questions ;-)

Comment: Well no it really didn't.. I create a new project -> create new Servlet -> and try my above code and it breaks

Comment: @user4640007 but are you still getting the same error message? Even after including `super.init(cfg)`?

Comment: Ok that got the bugger! Much obliged.